# Change combobox values based on a button click c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, relaycommand

I'm trying to transition from WinForm to WPF, and while studying this topic i came across this challenge,

> change combobox items upon a button click and create a button that
>   shows the original selected value"

I managed to do this with inline `RelayCommand` but it seems to me that I'm breaking the MVVM pattern and also it does not comply to that part "button that shows the original selected value",  so i continued reading and i found out that i can use `IValueConverter`. But i cannot figure out to connect between the button click and the converter(is this even possible, or i need to do something else?)

**my viewModel**

```
 class MainWindowVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainWindowVM()
        {
            CBItems = new ObservableCollection<double>();
            for (int i = 985; i <= 1030; i++)
                CBItems.Add(i);
            CBSelectedValue = 1013;

            testCmd = new RelayCommand(p =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < CBItems.Count; i++)
                { 
                    if(p.Equals("inHg"))
                    {
                        CBItems[i] *= 33.86;
                        ConversionUnit = "milibar";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        CBItems[i] /= 33.86;
                        ConversionUnit = "inHg";
                    }
                }
            }
        );

            SetQNH = new RelayCommand(p => MessageBox.Show(string.Format("QNH = {0}", Convert.ToInt32(p))));

        }

        public RelayCommand SetQNH { get; set; }         
        public RelayCommand testCmd { get; set; }


        private ObservableCollection<double> _CBItems;
        public ObservableCollection<double> CBItems
        {
            get { return _CBItems; }
            set
            {
                _CBItems = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CBItems");
            }
        }

        private string _conversionUnit;

        public string ConversionUnit
        {
            get { return _conversionUnit; }
            set
            {
                _conversionUnit = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ConversionUnit");
            }
        }

        private int _CBSelectedValue;
        public int CBSelectedValue {
            get { return _CBSelectedValue; }
            set
            {
                _CBSelectedValue = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CBSelectedValue");                  
            }
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string s)
        {
            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(s));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;             
    }
}
```

**my window**

```
<Window x:Class="QNH.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:QNH"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="318" Width="638">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:IUnitsValueConverter x:Key="MyConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowVM/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox  Name="cb" ItemsSource="{Binding CBItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding CBSelectedValue}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="406,136,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" >
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MyConverter} }"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>

        </ComboBox>


        <Button Name="Unit" Content="{Binding ConversionUnit, TargetNullValue=inHg}"
                Command="{Binding testCmd}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=Unit, Path=Content}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="140,136,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <Button Content="SET" Command="{Binding SetQNH}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=cb, Path=SelectedValue}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="406,163,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**and my converter**

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(int), typeof(double))]
    public class IUnitsValueConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            //var val = (int?)value;
            //if (val == null)
            //    return -1;

            return value;//* 33.86;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why would using a RelayCommand breakt the MVVM pattern?

Comment: @mm8 i really don't know, i copied from some examples i found

Comment: What exactly are you asking here? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @mm8 im trying to solve this challenge(as written the original post) **change combobox items upon a button click and create a button that shows the original selected value**

Comment: And where does the converter come in? What's wrong with your current code?

Comment: @mm8 what do you mean? and its wrong because, as i said it breaks the part of "button that shows the original selected value"

Comment: So don't set the `ConversionUnit` in the `Execute` method of the command? Or bind the `Content` property to `CBSelectedValue`? Also, the `CommandParameter` seems unecessary since you can access the `ConversionUnit` property directly in the `Execute` method.

Comment: @styx on button click set `CBSelectedValue=CBItems[0]` it will change on UI. note I used 0 as an example

Comment: @mm8 i have a hard time following what you are trying to say, if you may show me what you mean

Comment: @Avinash why should i do it, isnt `OnPropertyChanged` should do it?

Comment: @styx `OnPropertyChanged` will update the UI from VM but on button click, u wanna change `ComboBox` item how that will work?

Comment: @Avinash i dont know, and it seems the UI does not update

Comment: @styx I'm still confused what ur trying to do just let me know wt ur trying to do I will try to give an example as ur still new

Comment: @Avinash Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192041/discussion-between-styx-and-avinash).